# Add additional button to shopping cart nopCommerce

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, plugins, nopcommerce

I want to write a plugin that adds a new button to the shopping cart.

This button would be the third one beside the update button and the continue button.

In the picture you can see a red button like the one I would like to add.
The picture is just a demo. THe proportions are off.

I have a customViewEngine.

And this is my Configure.cshtml of my plugin.
I knwo I could change the OrderSummery.cshtml but I want to do it via a plugin.

```
@model ShoppingCartModel

@using Nop.Web.Models.ShoppingCart;

@{

    <input type="submit" name="continueshopping2" value="@T("ShoppingCart.ContinueShopping")" class="button-2 continue-shopping-button" />
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#continueshopping2").appendTo(".cart-options .common-buttons");
    });
    </script>

}

Hello World!
```

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3xTY.jpg)

My Second aproach was:

Copy the original OrderSummery.cshtml in my `Views` folder. 
That should override the original. But this isn't working.

Full plugin code below.

[Full Code](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AsYYSVzzwhqzgYIQRNcWyq7Zbx3YpQ)

Comment: It's easy! Use plugin view engine in plugin and give path of your view page which you copied, application will override that view page!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work you need a index.cshtml.

With this code.

```
<input type="submit" id="check-cart-button" value="Check Cart Button" class="button-2 continue-shopping-button" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#check-cart-button").appendTo(".cart-options .common-buttons");
    });
</script>
```

And in the Plugin.cs

you have to add

```
public IList<string> GetWidgetZones()
{
    return new[] { "order_summary_content_after" };
}

public void GetDisplayWidgetRoute(string widgetZone, out string actionName, out string controllerName, out RouteValueDictionary routeValues)
{
    actionName = "Index";
    controllerName = "CheckCart";
    routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary {
        { "Namespaces", "Nop.Plugin.Misc.CheckCart.Controllers" },
        { "area", null },
        { "widgetZone", widgetZone }
    };
}
```

This fixed my project.

The code above is neede beaucse you need to redirect the root.

Comment: WIth my selfanswerd code it has been solved. But thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:
Add `ShoppingCart` folder into the plugin view folder. And add `OrderSummary.cshtml` file into `ShoppingCart` folder.
Now Add PluginviewEngine.cs to your plugin and this code.

```
 public PluginViewEngine()
        {
            PartialViewLocationFormats =
                new[]
                {     //themes
                      "~/Themes/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",                   
                     "~/Plugins/Yourpluginname/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml"
                };

            ViewLocationFormats =
                new[]
                {      
                     //themes
                      "~/Themes/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
                     "~/Plugins/YourPluginName/Views/ShoppingCart/{0}.cshtml"
                };
        }
```

Hope this will help you!